# Running count from excel to access

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have the following formula in Excel:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A3,B:B,B3)-COUNTIFS(A4:A$1992,A3,B4:B$1992,B3)
```

[image: Excel output]

How do I create this same output from the `COUNTIFS` function in Access? My knowledge of Access functions and/or VBA is not strong as I have just began working with Access some time ago.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try DCOUNT.

https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dcount.php

Or, call that Excel function from Access.

```
Dim xls As Excel.Application    
Set xls = New Excel.Application

' Begin loop.
    bt = xls.WorksheetFunction.COUNTIFS(your_logic_here)
' End loop.  

xls.Quit
Set xls = Nothing
```

I don't know COUNTIFS well, but it would have arguments like this . . .

[image]